# Poly build tool, how do you drag/move a vertex?

Tags: modeling

I have to create a mesh with the poly build tool which I never used but would be perfect for what I'm trying to do. But what's the shortcut to simply move a vertex without 'leaving' the poly build tool?

In this video you can see it in action: https://youtu.be/U3sY3f6aKB8?t=153
But I don't see any specific shortcut, and I've tried everything I could think of to replicate this.

So, with poly build tool, how do I move an existing vertex without creating a new one?

PS: Also I can't find anything on the poly build tool in Blender's documentation...